# How to scale a lot of Records on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, data-modeling, scaling

I´m thinking about to write an application will have to store a small amount of records per user (<300) but hopefully will have a lot of users (>>1000). 
I did some research for a platform that allows starting small and scale if there is a need to do so and got stuck with App Engine, but I´m not sure if it is the right tool for it, especially the datastore.

How will I get it to scale if I have a User entity and a Message entity and store all users and messages in that entities? I think the amount of records in the entities will grow really big and filtering i.e. for all messages of a user will get expensive. Is that a problem or will Google handle that ? Do I have to introduce multitenancy and create a namespace for each user so I only see the records in the entities that relates to the user? Is there a limit for the number of namespaces ? What would be the right approach for modeling the data in the datastore?

I do not really have a clue how to handle the App Engine datastore and if its the right tool for me.

Comment: Just to be clear, you don't have a User entity and a Message entity, you have a user entity *kind* and a Message *kind*, defined by a User model and a Message model. What you're calling a "record", is an entity.

Comment: So to understand it right: the Models are the types and the entities are the instances of that type? And if so does the number of instances per type matter (time to process filtering, maximum qutoa limit) or only the number of instances i retrieve through filtering ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The App Engine datastore is explicitly designed to handle this kind of scalability. Queries execute in time proportional to the number of records returned, so fetching all a user's messages will take the same time regardless of how many users there are in the system.

Answer (score 1):

I think with those kind of numbers you are probably ok in terms of scalability.  anywhere from 300,000 to millions of records is easily handled by any serious datastore.

Answer (score 1):

It is not advisable to think of scaling during the infancy of your project.. Your first step should always be to build an app/product and launch it... Scaling comes afterwords Most of the app/products that are launched these days never make it to the level where they need to scale.. even if you do make or launch such a website/product/app that gets hit by large amount of traffic and you need to scale, then rejoice!!! because you've made it to that level.. But how to get to that level should always be the first question...

I'm not trying to de-moralise you, rather trying to help you focus where you should be... Thanks for reading and good luck with your App! May you do need to scale and as Toby said, even the most basic App Engine configuration is good enough to handle a couple of hundred thousands of records...

Comment: Terrible advice. Ask Twitter how much they like the "worry about scalability later" approach.

Comment: You don't have to put in every last micro-optimization from the start, but you do need to choose a platform that can let you scale anywhere you want to go. The last thing you want is to get to the point where you're about to call your app "successful" (whether that's defined as profitable, IPO-worthy, or just popular with a large number of people), and discover you have to re-write it from scratch on a different platform, because you've hit the fundamental limits of the old one.

Comment: @Nick, no offense sir, but I do wonder that how many companies are out there who made it to the same level as Twitter? Twitter is in a position where they've hit the limits of linear scalibility. I doubt out of the thousands of websites launched each year how many make it to the level where they have to face with issues of scalability? And scalibility is more of an architecture issue than code. Just because you have rails with n to the power x foolish loops in ur code doesn't mean rails is not performing or scalable.You refactor the code and move to a better architecture when you need 2 scale.

Comment: @Steve: I agree with you completely, that's the way to scale. I'm sure if max does has to face the issue of scalability he can always move off from Google App Engine, in case it's not satisfying his requirements: which I believe is vague and would not happen.

Comment: I don't think you do agree with me completely, because I think it's worth considering now whether the platform can support the level of scaling that constitutes "success", in order to avoid having to move off the first platform, and therefore probably rewrite the whole app, at some crucial growth point. There is absolutely no point designing an app in such a way that if it approaches success, it will fail anyway. Just because most projects fail doesn't mean max should set out to make sure his is one of them. App Engine supports building in scalability early, if you get to grips with it.

Comment: Anyway, this is a meta-discussion about whether max should have asked the question. The answer to the question is basically, "yes, App Engine can support that kind of scale without major difficulty".

Comment: I do agree with what you said, it would be unwise to move ahead by completely ignoring the scalability factor, but as you said more concentration should be towards your product and not the worries of 100 million users a month userbase  that might take years to build up?

Comment: I'm sorry, I think I did mis interpreted you. I do agree with what you said in the first line: you don't need to worry about the micro optimizations in your app.

Comment: Lol :) yes, I think we are taking it completely off track.. Yes max the answer to your question is yes.. Go ahead with App Engine! :) good luck!

Comment: :D nice discussion guys! Yeah I know that scaling is not the key point at my project state, but the intention was more the technical point; how to model the datastore entities so that app engine will do the basic scaling for me without to rewrite the whole codebase in a later point. I´m a little bit confused about the datastore at the moment, because blogs writes it does not behave like the typical relational database, but it seems throwing all records in one entity and get as few as possible through filtering is a walkable way?